# Force Excel to re-parse a whole column of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a series of dates in a column, currently recognized as text. Thus sorting doesn't work correctly.

[image]

When highlighting the column and changing the format to `Date`, Excel still recognizes it as text (you can notice it: it stays left-aligned).

The only solution I've found is to go on each cell individually and hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If there are many cells, going to the top and hitting <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.... is not really an option.

**What faster solution is there?**

[Doing a multiplication by 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/52qor2/quickeasy_way_to_activate_and_confirm_cells_f2/d7merct/) seems to work but is there a nicer way?

Comment: Text to Columns, do not split on anything.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think you can post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Scott in a comment, selecting one single column and using the feature `Text to columns` (with no splitting at all) solves the problem.

[image]